# Can Resharper format case statements to start on the same line as the case itself?

Tags: c#, formatting, resharper, switch-statement

I'm trying to find a way to have Resharper format a switch statement like this (using Ctrl+E, Ctrl+C):

```
switch (int_i) {
    case 1  : Console.WriteLine("You entered one");
              break;
    case 2  : Console.WriteLine("You entered two");
              break;
    case 3  : Console.WriteLine("You entered three");
              break;
    default : Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number between 1 and 5");
              break;
}
```

I personally don't like this style at all, but it's being used in a book I'm studying and I'd like Resharper to help me format my code the same way.

There are two things to note here:

1. The statements have to start on the same line as the case statement.
2. The colons have to be aligned, so because `default` is longer than `case 3` there has to be an extra space before the colon on `case 1`, `case 2` and `case 3`.

Can Resharper do this?

Comment: So you don't like the style, and formatting it like in the book isn't adding any value to your ability to learn from the book, but you want to spend time trying to figure out how to format it this way? I can see a minimal amount of value in learning how to use ReSharper to do this, but frankly I'd focus my efforts on acquiring skills more fruitful than this. Also, I hope that the book you're learning from didn't give you the variable name `int_i`; that is awful. Sorry, it's hard to not sound like a jerk in 600 characters.

Comment: @Jason completely agree, but if the code samples were complex and the book referenced "line 123" without any other context it might be useful to have the samples line up.

Comment: @ Jason: I was disappointed to see a variable named `int_i` too. It _does_ come from the book however.

Comment: @ Tim Medora: Line numbers are indeed the main reason why I want to use the same coding style.

Comment: @comecme: What book is it? That is so awful I'd consider another book on the same subject were one available.

Comment: The book is [C# for Artists: the Art, Philosophy, and Science of Object-Oriented Programming](http://www.pulpfreepress.com/content/Products/Books/CSharp_For_Artists/1-932504-07-9.shtml).

Comment: I chose this book because I was looking for a book that would teach me about C# in combination with a "real" Object Oriented approach. I'm not sure yet if this book does that as the chapters I've read so far only cover basic C# coding. I'm hoping to read about how to form real world problems into objects in stead of only small examples using things like `foo` and `bar`. This book seems to promise that.

Comment: The book probably formats it that way so it takes up less vertical space, therefore fewer pages. Same reason I put my `{`s at the end of the line when I'm posting code on SO (and it's showing up in one answer out of many), when I wouldn't dream of doing that in real code. Still, it's crass of them to reference line numbers without showing them in the listings.

Comment: @Joe: The listings in the book off course *do* contain line numbers. AFAIK there is no option to post code on SO including linenumbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize code formatting in **ReSharper - Options - Languages - C# - Formatting Style**, but it seems there is nothing about you are asking. Closest thing I found - braces formatting in Switch statement.

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer. I already knew you can customize formatting, my question was if it was possible to get the formatting I described.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but it is possible.  It's just not obvious.  I just now stumbled on to it.

Go to ReSharper Options/Code Editing/C#/Format Style/Braces Layout.  Select 'Block under "case" label' to see that the sample is wrong. Now select Other.  Set it to "At end of line (K&R Style)".  Nothing in the sample will change.  Select 'Block under "case" label' again to see that the formatting is now correct.

I prefer BSD style which also works.

Comment: When I change the "Other" setting from "At next line (BSD style)" to "At end of line (K&R Style)", I do see a change in the sample. When I switch back to "Block under 'case' label" I don't see a change.
So I have Other: "end of line (K&R)" and Block under case label: "At next line (BSD)".

Answer (score 0):

I think there is now an option for that. I have the version 2017.3.2.

Got to ReSharper Options/Code Editing/C#/Formatting Style/Line Breaks and Wrapping/Arrangement of Embedded Statements and set Place simple "case" statement on same line to Always.

Comment: That does not work for my example. Because each `case` has two lines (the `WriteLine` and the `break`), ReSharper doesn't consider it a _simple_ case statement, so it will still place a line break after each `case`. And even with just one statement, it won't align the colons. It would just put a single space between the `case` and the statement.